# Crossfire 5870's

Tags: graphics-card, crossfire

Recently, I got another HD 5870 to crossfire with the original one in my machine. They are made by different manufacturers but everything else is the same. I tested each card individually and they both worked fine. Unfortunately, if I have both in the system at the same time, it won't post. I know the power supply and video cards are not the issue but i can't real

Comment: looks like you question go cut off. anyway, have you checked your motherboard for an auxilary power connector somewhere near the PCIe slots?

Comment: if the mobo allows asymmetric crossfire, I can't imagine symmetric crossfire with different vendors being a problem...Xantec brings up a good point.  It sounds like power/not seated to me.

Comment: I checked and there is no auxilary power connector and I also made sure both cards were seated well and I still had problems

Answer (score 0):

This is very, very likely to be a power supply related issue in my experience.

Two high end video cards draw [a LOT of power](http://techreport.com/articles.x/17618/15):

[image]

Going from one 5870 to two means +170w under load, and +26w at idle.